# Dynamically name function with template or generics

Tags: java, c++, oop

Is there any way of dynamically or precompile name a method or function in Java or C++ based on the generics or template used? Here is a code to draw the idea:

Java:

```
class Adder<T, R> {
    add"T"(T t);
    add"R"(R r);
}
...
obj = new Adder<MyClass, ClassTwo>();
obj.addMyClass(myObject);
obj.addClassTwo(objectTwo);
```

A more concrete example: A Vector Space defined in Matrix set, in Real set, has definied a matrix multiplication that returns a matrix (Matrix X Matrix) and a real multiplication that also return a matrix (Real X Matrix), with diferrent implementations. e.g.:

```
intereface VectorSpace<T, R> {
    ...
    T multiply"T" (T arg0, T arg1);
    T multiply"R" (T arg0, R arg1);
}
...
class RealMatrixVectorSpace implements VectorSpace<Matrix, Real> {
    Matrix multiplyMatrix (Matrix arg0, Matrix arg1) { ... }
    Matrix multiplyReal (Matrix arg0, Real arg1) { ... }
}
```

But a vector space can be defined with other inputs, that what I'm trying to define for a program to utilize this generic concept.

Comment: evil MACRO in C++, but what's wrong with `Adder<MyClass>().add(myObject)` ?

Comment: dont confuse java generics with c++ templates, they are quite different beasts. Its basically two questions in one

Comment: Wait what? How on earth would it not matter to you if it was in Java or C++? Do you even have a goal in mind?

Comment: if you want the method to have different names, then why are they supposed to be instantiations of the same template? Suggest you read on the [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Knowing a use case can help to answer the question (and sometimes it is necessary to give a correct answer)

Comment: The only option in c++ is `obj.add<MyClass>` and `obj.add<ClassTwo>`

Comment: @Jarod42, it may be useful when using more then one input parameter. Just updated the question

Comment: implementation of those methods should be the same, only different names?

Comment: @LBald but would these methods do different things, or do they do the same thing? If they do the same thing, why should they be named differently? If they do different things, how could they be generic?

Comment: @LBald I would not recommend choosing language based on that. Java and C++ are really different. You should probably choose one or the other based e.g. on performance constraints and make your design fit particular language.

Comment: Thanks @user463035818, just updated the question

Comment: @LBald how would you use that interface `VectorSpace`?

Comment: Maybe I'm making a storm in a teacup. Thanks everyone ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No and there is no need for such a feature. In your example you could easily use **Method Overloading**. (Does not work in Java)

```
// c++
template <typename T, typename R>
class Adder
{
    void add(T t);
    void add(R r);
}
```

The correct function is selected automatically at compile time. (Note: Does only work if T and R do not have the same Type)

Comment: This would only work in java if `T` and `R` are bounded to yield different erasure.

Comment: in c++ also only when `T` is not the same as `R`

Answer (score 2):

I personally think that - as mentioned by @Jarod42 - a solution like  `Adder<MyClass>().add(myObject)` is sufficient; There is in my opinion no need to express the context of `MyClass` twice, i.e. once through template parameter and a second time through the name of a member function of this parametrized class.

Anyway, if you are looking for something like that, you'll need something in the preprocessor, since you are about generating tokens. You could achieve this through token concatenation makro `##` as follows.

But caution: such kind of code is usually rather tricky, uncommon, and error prone and I do not recommend using it:

```
#define CLASSDEF(NAME) class NAME ## Adder { public:  void add(NAME ## Adder a); }

CLASSDEF(MyClass);
CLASSDEF(AnotherClass);

int main() {
    MyClassAdder x;
    x.add(x);

    AnotherClassAdder y;
    y.add(y);
}
```

For java, in contrast, I don't think that you can achieve something similar; To my knowledge, there is no way to "dynamically" create tokens in some sort of preprocessor.

Comment: I can't see a real life reason to do this, but yes it is tricky uncommon and error prone :P

Comment: Isnt that different from what the OP asked? I think he meant both adds in the same class with a method posfix

Comment: @BigMike: yes, it's "beautifull" (for someone with a very special sense of aesthetics) :-)

Comment: @Phins: yes; question seems to have changed while writing my answer. In this case, a makro just for the method definition would be sufficient.